# BibLaTeX customize misc citation, add dot

Tags: biblatex, iso

I am writing a document with multiple bibliography types according to the ISO 690 specification.

I have this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[headheight=2cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hyphens, spaces, obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% ...

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,style=iso-authoryear,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Zdroje/Zdroje.bib}

% ...

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{urldate}{[cit. #1].}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{Dostupné z: #1}

% ...

\begin{document}

% ...

%\include{...}

Some text\footfullcite{example}.

% ...

\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,type=misc,heading=subbibliography,title={Online zdroje}]

% ...

\end{document}
```

and `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@misc{example,
    title = {{exmp}, a.s. - {Detail} - {example}.cz},
    url = {https://www.exmp.cz/search/detail/cz-12345678/},
    urldate = {2021-12-27},
}
```

I insert bibliography using: `\footfullcite{key}`.

Everything works fine, except the bibliography entry for the misc type is not printed correctly according to the iso-690 specification.

From compiling the MWE, I get this:

[image]

What I would like to get instead is:

> *exmp, a.s. - Detail - example.cz* [online]. [cit. 2021-12-27]. Dostupné z: https://www.exmp.cz/search/detail/cz-12345678/

please note the dot after `[online]`.

I tried to `\DeclareFieldFormat` for:

- `howpublished`,
- `eprint`,
- `eprintclass`,
- `eprinttype`.

However nothing worked and I have not managed to add the dot after the `[online]` part, could you please help me?

---

Update:

Issue opened in the biblatex-iso690 project.

Unfortunately I failed at redefining the macro, however for anyone iterested I found a quick and dirty workaroud for this problem.

It is possible to define `howpublished = {online}` for the entry in a bibfile, once that is done the `howpublished` literal can be accessed by the `\DeclareFieldFormat` and changed accordingly: `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{howpublished}{[#1].}`, however as moewe stated, this is probably not the best solution.

For the time being, until the issue is resolved, I have created a simple python script and makefile to compile my project with the punctuation between the `howpublished` and the `urldate` fields.

Please note, that I am by no means Make expert, so there might be a better way to do this.

Makefile:

```
TEXFILE := Strategický_audit # <= Change the texfile name here
BIBFILE := Zdroje/Zdroje.bib # <= Change the bib file location here
TEXENGINE=pdflatex
BIBLATEX=biber
BUILDFLAGS=-output-directory=out
FOLDER=out
BUILDTEX=$(TEXENGINE) $(BUILDFLAGS) $(TEXFILE)

.PHONY: all
.PHONY: prepareBib
.PHONE: clear
.PHONY: clean
.PHONE: prepareOut

build: prepareBib prepareOut
    $(BUILDTEX)
    $(BIBLATEX) $(FOLDER)/$(TEXFILE)
    $(BUILDTEX)
    $(BUILDTEX)
    cp out/$(TEXFILE).pdf .

prepareBib:
    python3 prepare_bib.py $(BIBFILE)

prepareOut:
    ./create_subdirectories.sh

clear: clean
    @rm -f $(TEXFILE).pdf; \

clean:
    @rm -rf $(FOLDER);

help:
    @echo "build:    Generate pdf file."; \
     echo "clear:    Delete all generated files."; \
     echo "clean:    Delete all temporary files."; \
     echo "help:     Print help for Makefile."

all: build clean
```

Python script:

```python
"""File to parse and prepare the bib file for the LaTeX compilation."""

from typing import Iterable, Any, Tuple
import copy
import sys

prefixes: list = ["@misc", "@online"]

def check_if_field_already_exists(it:Iterable[Any], field: str) -> bool:
    return any(field in string for string in it)

def check_if_online_entry(it:Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
    return it[0].startswith(tuple(prefixes))

def is_element_last_in_iterable(it:Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[Tuple[bool, Any]]:
    iterable = iter(it)
    ret_var = next(iterable)
    for val in iterable:
        yield False, ret_var
        ret_var = val
    yield True, ret_var

def main(bib_file_location: str) -> None:

    list_of_entries = []
    temp_list = []

    try:
        with open(bib_file_location, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Provided file was not found.")
        exit(1)

    for line in lines:
        if line == "\n":
            continue
        temp_list.append(line)
        if line == "}\n" or line == "}":
            list_of_entries.append(copy.deepcopy(temp_list))
            temp_list.clear()

    with open(bib_file_location, "w") as f:
        for entry in list_of_entries:
            if not (is_online := check_if_online_entry(entry)):
                for is_last_element, var in is_element_last_in_iterable(entry):
                    if is_last_element:
                        f.write("{}\n".format(var))
                    else:
                        f.write(var)
            if is_online:
                if check_if_field_already_exists(entry, "howpublished"):
                    for is_last_element, var in is_element_last_in_iterable(entry):
                        if is_last_element:
                            f.write("{}\n".format(var))
                        else:
                            f.write(var)
                else:
                    for is_last_element, var in is_element_last_in_iterable(entry):
                        if is_last_element:
                            f.write("\thowpublished = {{online}},\n{}\n".format(var))
                        else:
                            f.write(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("Please provide the bib file location.")
        exit(1)
```

Bash script to prepare the environment for the compilation:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

create_subdirectories () {
    for OUTPUT in $(find . -type d)
    do
        if [[ $OUTPUT == *".texpadtmp"* ]] || [[ $OUTPUT == *"out"* ]] || [[ $OUTPUT == "." ]]; then
            :
        else
            mkdir -p out/"${OUTPUT#"./"}"
        fi
    done
}

copy_folder_structure () {
for OUTPUT in $(find . -type f -name "*.tex" -o -name "*.bib" -o -name "*.png")
    do
        if [[ $OUTPUT == "./out/"* ]]; then
            :
        else
            cp -R "${OUTPUT}" out/"${OUTPUT#"./"}"
        fi
    done
}

create_subdirectories
copy_folder_structure
```

Please note that the Makefile will only work if the bib file is in particular format (I am using Zotero).

Comment: If the output of a `biblatex-iso690` does not conform to ISO 690 (or the more strict Czech interpretation), please open a bug report at https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/issues. Include the example entry as well as a reference to the section of the standard that is relevant here.

Comment: Generally speaking `\DeclareFieldFormat` is not the correct tool to insert punctuation between, before or after fields. There should not be leading or trailing punctuation in a `\DeclareFieldFormat` definition. The punctuation between fields needs to be controlled with `\setunit` in the relevant bibmacros or drivers.

Comment: Probably not that relevant to your issue, but it is much more natural to use the type `@online` for online resources instead of `@misc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to posting an issue to the biblatex-iso690 project, I manage to fix the problem by redefining the macro the following way:

```latex
\providetoggle{bbx:url}

% The url seen date of @online entries is always printed
\renewbibmacro*{urldate}{%
  % if there is no publisher specified in the bib file, set unit to period
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iflistundef{publisher}}%
    and test {\iflistundef{location}}%
  }{\setunit{\adddot\addspace}}%
  {\setunit{\addspace}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iftoggle{bbx:url}}
    or test {\ifentrytype{online}}
  }
    {\printurldate}%
    {}%
}
```

Please note that the solution is for the online entry type.